# Finding backgroundworker object by its name in C#

Tags: c#, controls, backgroundworker

How can I find a backgroundworker's object using its name? For controls I can use Find to get access to control based on its name:

```
Control Control = this.Controls.Find(ControlName, true)[0];
```

How about backgroundworkers and/or timers? Controls.Find can not find them.

Comment: You should just keep track of your backgroundworkers and timers by using class members or the like.

Comment: Reflection is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, because there is no public object which tracks references to Background workers or timers.

You can store references to all background workers by yourself:

```
public static List<BackgroundWorkers> Workers {get; set;}

static()
{
    Workers = new List<BackgroundWorkers>();
}
```

Save reference to worker when you create one:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
Workers.Add(worker);
```

You also may give a name to each worker by storing workers in `Dictionary<string, BackgroundWorker>`

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
Workers.Add("workerName", worker);

BackgroundWorker myWorker = Workers["workerName"];
```

Comment: A `Dictionary` is better for the OP's problem because ha can assign a name (key) to each worker.

Comment: so, the short answer is: not possible without storing references. Am I right? No way to do the same way I explained with controls?

Comment: Yes, it's not possible w/o storing references. You can access controls because framework stores references internally and provides you access to it's collection.

Comment: so please add this to the beginning of your answer as this is the direct answer to my question and I will mark it as answer.

Comment: :) thanks, please mark `msporek`'s answer as correct. He already wrote this.

Comment: True, but your answer was more comprehensive and informative and I'd like to mark it as answer if you mention this as well :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it, just keep a reference to your BackgroundWorkers, there is no other way.